# Converting an LAS object back to a LAS files (.las) using the lidR R package

Tags: lidar, las, lidr

I'm using the R package lidR to classify noise in a LiDAR dataset, but I would like to save the final LAS object as a LAS file to open it on another software.

How can I accomplish that?

Note that I'm not trying to convert the LAS object into a point shapefile, but back to a LAS file.

Moreover, my project area has more than 1,000 LAS tiles, should I use a loop to classify noise on all files or read them as `LAScatalog` and run the tool `classify_noise()` on the `LAScatalog`?

If the latter, how can I save a `LAScatalog` as multiple LAS tiles (with exactly the same number and dimensions of the input LAS files)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Answer (score 2):

Your question and the way you are asking make me think that you did not read any tutorial about `lidR`. You can read the [online book](https://jean-romain.github.io/lidRbook/) and more specifically the [chapter about catalog processing](https://jean-romain.github.io/lidRbook/engine.html).

Something like that will process your collection:

```r
ctg <- readALSLAScatalog('folder/')
opt_output_files(ctg) <- paste0("folder/noise_classified/{ORIGINALFILENAME}")
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 0
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 10
ctg2 <- classify_noise(ctg , algorithm = ivf())
```